How can I label a vertical line at the bottom of a chart in Pinescript
I am trying to plot some labels at the bottom of a chart that coincide with vertical lines. I've made a formula that will plot a line at different intervals and I just want to label each line. At the moment I've got labels plotting at the correct intervals but it would look a lot better if I could move them all down to the bottom of the chart . It's for a relative strength chart. Any help really appreciated. I've searched everywhere and I can't do it.
Thanks
`//@version=5
indicator("Year Markers", overlay = true)
Bars3Mths = timeframe.ismonthly ? 3: timeframe.isweekly ? 13 : timeframe.isdaily ? 63 :na
Bars6Mths = timeframe.ismonthly ? 6: timeframe.isweekly ? 26 : timeframe.isdaily ? 126 :na
Bars9Mths = timeframe.ismonthly ? 9: timeframe.isweekly ? 39 : timeframe.isdaily ? 189 :na
Bars1Yr = timeframe.ismonthly ? 12: timeframe.isweekly ? 52 : timeframe.isdaily ? 252 :na
Bars3Yrs = timeframe.ismonthly ? 36: timeframe.isweekly ? 156 : timeframe.isdaily ? 756 :na
Bars5Yrs = timeframe.ismonthly ? 60: timeframe.isweekly ? 260 : timeframe.isdaily ? 1260 :na
Bars10Yrs = timeframe.ismonthly ? 120: timeframe.isweekly ? 520 : timeframe.isdaily ? 2520 :na
Bars15Yrs = timeframe.ismonthly ? 180: timeframe.isweekly ? 780 : timeframe.isdaily ? 3780 :na
Bars20Yrs = timeframe.ismonthly ? 240: timeframe.isweekly ? 1040 : timeframe.isdaily ? 5040 :na
M3 = label.new(bar_index-Bars3Mths, ta.lowest(low,Bars3Mths)*0.98 , text = "3 Months" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(M3[1])
M6 = label.new(bar_index-Bars6Mths, ta.lowest(low,Bars6Mths)*0.98 , text = "6 Months" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(M6[1])
M9 = label.new(bar_index-Bars9Mths, ta.lowest(low,Bars9Mths)*0.98 , text = "9 Months" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(M9[1])
Y1 = label.new(bar_index-Bars1Yr, ta.lowest(low,Bars1Yr)*0.98 , text = "1 Year" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(Y1[1])
Y3 = label.new(bar_index-Bars3Yrs, ta.lowest(low,Bars3Yrs)*0.98, text = "3 Years" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(Y3[1])
Y5 = label.new(bar_index-Bars5Yrs, ta.lowest(low,Bars5Yrs)*0.98, text = "5 Years" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(Y5[1])
Y10 = label.new(bar_index-Bars10Yrs, ta.lowest(low,Bars10Yrs)*0.98, text = "10 Years" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(Y10[1])
Y15 = label.new(bar_index-Bars15Yrs, ta.lowest(low,Bars15Yrs)*0.98, text = "15 Years" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(Y15[1])
Y20 = label.new(bar_index-Bars20Yrs, ta.lowest(low,Bars20Yrs)*0.98, text = "20 Years" , textcolor = color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
label.delete(Y20[1])
if barstate.islast
line.new(bar_index-Bars3Mths, close, bar_index-Bars3Mths, close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars6Mths, close, bar_index-Bars6Mths, close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars9Mths, close, bar_index-Bars9Mths, close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars1Yr ,  close, bar_index-Bars1Yr,   close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars3Yrs,  close, bar_index-Bars3Yrs,  close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars5Yrs,  close, bar_index-Bars5Yrs,  close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars10Yrs, close, bar_index-Bars10Yrs, close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars15Yrs, close, bar_index-Bars15Yrs, close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
line.new(bar_index-Bars20Yrs, close, bar_index-Bars20Yrs, close, extend=extend.both, color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)`
